# statement to check if the datetime is within the two datetime from the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 column, `start_date` and `end_date` which contains a date and time with "`yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:tt`" format. At my program, I wanna query with this logic:

If current_date is between start_date and end_date, return **`True`**. But the start_date and end_date is not static. Variety of value for each column.

**How to make a query statement to check if the current date is between start_date and end_date for every row**?

Answer for Alex:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select if(start_date<=now() and now()<=end_date,true,false) from table
```

You will get `1 (true)` or `0 (false)`.

Comment: that is the result from the query. It should be normal to view all data? And yes. If the now() is valid in between those two column, it will fill with value: 1..